# Flexbox Item Animation

Tags: html, css, animation, flexbox

I have a flexbox container which increases in width when I hover over it. The items in the flexbox just move traditionally when this happens. How can I animate the movement of items in the flexbox?

Here's [a link](https://jsfiddle.net/kpcgru81/4/) to what I've tried.

I've tried using flex-direction and transition, but no luck.
This is the code block that triggers the hover:

```
section:hover{
   width: 500px;
}
```

Comment: What specifically do you want to animate? The rearrangement of the items?

Comment: Yes. I wanna animate that.

Comment: Would like to know the style of animation you want.

Comment: I'd like it this way: The first item stays as it is, obviously. The second and third item should move slowly with the pace of the section (2s)

Comment: So you want the div to drop at the bottom with some ease effect and not right away.
Smoother transition, right?

Comment: https://codepen.io/osublake/pen/dMLQJr?editors=0010, just for some reference

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the reference!